# não estou conseguindo fazer um postBack no meu projeto

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2.2

estou tentando fazer um postBack no meu projeto só que não estou conseguindo.

Quando submeto o formulário ele continua fazendo select sem precisão. Ou seja, ficou no mesmo jeito

```
public class FacesUtil {

/**
 * Método que avalia se é postBack.
 * @return
 */
public boolean isPostback(){
    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback();
}

/**
 * Método que nega o PostBack
 * @return
 */
public static boolean isNotPostBack(){
    return !isNotPostBack();
}
```

}

meuBean

```
public void inicializar() {
    System.out.println("Inicializando Cadastro de Carro...");
    if(FacesUtil.isNotPostBack()){
        modeloCarros = modeloCarroService.buscarTodos();
    }

    if (this.carro == null) {
        limpar();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Qual o tipo de escopo de sessão que você está utilizando? session, view, request?

Já pensou em utilizar CDI para realizar um primeiro carregamento dos dados na sua página? No estilo:

```
@PostConstruct
public void inicializar() {
    modeloCarroService.buscarTodos();
}
```